# Datatable - Search for data in tooltip

Tags: datatables, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using client side rendering to render a table with data that is sometimes too long to display on a page. I therefore display only the first 50 characters and add a `...` with a tooltip containing all of the content.

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-container="body" title="@r.Items">
@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Items) ? "" : r.Items.Substring(0, Math.Min(r.Items.Length, 50)) + (r.Items.Length > 50 ? "..." : ""))
</td>
```

Is there any possible way to allow the search feature to search not only for the shortened content, but also for the tooltip?

Comment: The search already applies to a tooltip, what language are you using? I will create a sample to show you

Comment: ASP.NET Razor - C#

Comment: @BeerusDev would appreciate a sample